# How to group and transform count with pandas when the column has NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby, nan

I have a pandas dataframe that contains `np.nan` and I have to group it and get the count as so:

```
df.groupby('column')['column'].transform('count')
```

However, because of the `np.nan`, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 1009, index implies 0
```

What would be a good workarround?

Comment: Call dropna and remove NaNs?

Comment: @coldspeed, I can't quite do that. I can have cases where the entire column is np.nan

Comment: But you're grouping by a column which has NaNs. Does that make sense? Can we know more about your data?

Comment: @coldspeed that is right, I could be grouping by a column of only NaNs. That could be the problem actually, I didn't think of it. What happens is I'm using things in a function, so sometimes it may happen that all are NaN.